# Extend jquery plugin to check negative numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I use a jquery validation plugin and I need to add some extra checking, but I can't edit the main file. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own validation methods with [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function

Answer (score 0):

yes i get the solution  just taking this i got the solution  ,,  greaterThanZero is the class name  of field to be   checked

jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanZero", function(value, element) {
        console.log(element);
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d*.{0,1}\d+$/.test(value);
    }, "* Amount must be greater than zero");